# How to fill column with condition in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

I would like to add new column using other column value with condition

In pandas, I do this like below

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
df['c'] = df['a']
df.loc[df['b']==4, 'c'] = df['b']
```

The result is

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 |

Could you teach me how to do this with polars?

Comment: Does https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/coming_from_pandas.html?highlight=modify#column-assignment-based-on-predicate help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`when/then/otherwise`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html#polars.when)

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})

df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("b") == 4).then(pl.col('b')).otherwise(pl.col('a')).alias("c")
)
```